# asp net core - file download results is FileNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I'm trying to do a simple file download, but it results with FileNotFoundException.

The code in the controller:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile()
{
    var fileName = "1.pdf";
    var filePath = env.WebRootPath + "\\" + fileName;
    var fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(filePath);
    return File(filePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
}
```

(Debugging the variable fileExists shows that it's set to true.)

The code in the view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile")
```

Messages from the log:

```
2017-03-12 09:28:45 [INF] Executing action method "Team.Controllers.ModulesExController.DownloadFile (Team)" with arguments (null) - ModelState is Valid
2017-03-12 09:28:45 [DBG] Executed action method "Team.Controllers.ModulesExController.DownloadFile (Team)", returned result "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.VirtualFileResult".
2017-03-12 09:28:45 [INF] Executing FileResult, sending file as "1.pdf"
2017-03-12 09:28:45 [INF] Executed action "Team.Controllers.ModulesExController.DownloadFile (Team)" in 0.8238ms
2017-03-12 09:28:45 [DBG] System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred, checking if Entity Framework recorded this exception as resulting from a failed database operation.
2017-03-12 09:28:45 [DBG] Entity Framework did not record any exceptions due to failed database operations. This means the current exception is not a failed Entity Framework database operation, or the current exception occurred from a DbContext that was not obtained from request services.
2017-03-12 09:28:45 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: D:\Projekti\Team\src\Team\wwwroot\1.pdf
```

If I paste the link in the error message in the browser, I can open the file.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Controller.File()` is expecting a *virtual path*, not an absolute path.

**See** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_String_System_String_System_String_

If you want to use an absolute path, pass in a stream:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile()
{
    var fileName = "1.pdf";
    var filePath = env.WebRootPath + "\\" + fileName;
    var fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(filePath);
    var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);
    return File(fs, "application/pdf", fileName);
}
```

Comment: The link is now broken

Answer (score 31):

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 you can use a PhysicalFile as the return type if you have a file path.

```
    public FileResult DownloadFile() {
        var fileName = "1.pdf";
        var filePath = env.WebRootPath + "\\" + fileName;
        var fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(filePath);
        return PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
    }
```

Comment: What is the practical difference between your and the preceding answer?

Comment: 1. Less code (well one less line). 2. Not opening a stream that you are not closing. 3. A little cleaner code which is probably why they added it in Core 2.

Comment: Also, if you use stream I'm not sure if cashing headers are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This code downloads a pdf file named 'abc123.pdf' that you've put in your MVC 5 Resources folder. It took me several hours of stitching together other stack overflow articles to make it work. Most of the solutions I've seen don't tell you how to download the physical file. Most solutions don't mention how to deal with the resource file, which I find very useful.

```
    public IActionResult DownloadBlankACH()
    {

        return DownloadDocumentLikeThis("abc123");

    }

    private IActionResult DownloadDocumentLikeThis(string likeThis)
    {
        ResourceManager MyResourceClass = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources));

        ResourceSet resourceSet = MyResourceClass.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
        {
            string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
            object resource = entry.Value;
            if (resourceKey.Contains(likeThis))
            {
                string RunningPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                string FileName = string.Format("{0}Properties\\" + resourceKey + ".pdf", Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(RunningPath, @"..\..\..\")));

                return PhysicalFile(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileName), "application/pdf", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));

            }

        }


        return View();
    }
```